# Is "Verbockt" pejorative?

Tags: meaning

I came across word "verbockt". As far as I know, it translates to "messed up" or so. My question is, whether it's pejorative or not - so, if I can safely use it in normal conversations with friends etc. And who would normally use a word like this?

Comment: I think the question would benefit from some context about where you read it, how you want to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Verbockt" is in no way pejorative. Nobody will be offended if you use it in your friends group.
It is just informal and insofar you would rather not use it to describe an error to your boss although even there it might fit...

Answer (score 0):

There's the saying

> den Bock zum Gärtner machen — “to leave the gardening to the buck”

You would sure agree that this is a very bad idea. You can use that saying if you think the wrong person is in charge. And a similar thing is also meant with *verbocken*. It means to do something the very wrong way. As a buck would do it.

> Ich hab's verbockt. — I messed up.

It's a great word to talk about using the wrong method.

A similar word is *vergeigen*. Think of the world's tiniest violin.

Comment: I'm not sure that was the question since the meaning can be found in a dictionary. Is it informal, elevated, slang, obscene, offensive? DWDS says it's "umgangssprachlich". German Wiktionary has more information on "den Bock zum Gärtner machen".

Comment: I don't even think it's informal nowadays.

Answer (score -1):

Incidentally I just came across a case where "verbockt" was actively avoided: For the German voiceover of the New Zealand TV detective show *The Brokenwood Mysteries*, at one point the main character critizises his predecessor [(at about 33:30, link will only be available for one month)](https://www.ardmediathek.de/video/krimi-und-thriller/brokenwood-mord-in-neuseeland-blut-und-wasser-1-20/swr/Y3JpZDovL3N3ci5kZS9hZXgvbzE5NzgwMjg):

> Sie haben es [versiebt](https://www.dwds.de/wb/versieben?o=versiebt).

Unfortunately, the English voice track is not available at that streaming service. But from comparing a [subtitle service](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/6315292/the-brokenwood-mysteries-blood-water-en), it seems the original says "You screwed up" at this point.

So at least the translator of that scene, Markus Jütte, had a feeling that "verbockt" would be too strong and used the slightly more sedate "versiebt" instead. Compare the two DWDS dictionary definitions:

> verbocken – einen Fehler machen, etwas falsch machen, verderben
>
> versieben – etwas durch falsches Vorgehen verderben

They show only nuances in difference, but for me at least, the first metaphor, based on a smelly, ill-mannered animal is the stronger one than a man-made tool for sorting.

Comment: Pfff. Trying to put a difference in meaning between "etwas verbocken" und "etwas versieben" sounds a bit academic to me. Both, at least to me, have the exact same meaning.

Comment: There are plenty of other, imaginable reasons, why the translatore choose the one term over the other - you've got just one possible explanation, while it isn't even obvious that he considered "verbockt" at all.